# How to remove all styles from a text in python?

Tags: python, text, nlp

Is there any way to convert the following text messages into normal text in python?

```
msg1 = '  '
msg2 = 'ʜɪ ɴᴇᴡ ᴀᴄᴄ ʙʏ ɪɴᴅᴇхᴀᴛ'
msg3 = 'ᕼI ᐯᗩᑎI᙭ ᑎᗴᗯ ᕼIT'
```

I tried the following code and it worked fine for msg1 but not for msg2 and msg3

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', msg1)
```

output: 'hi vanix new'

but when I use the same code on msg2 and msg3, it is not working.

Comment: You can try the [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) package. However, since many of the characters in your example 2 and 3 are not meant to be stylized versions of Latin alphabets in the first place, but rather characters of an entirely different language that happen to look like cute versions of Latin alphabets, you will likely have to create your own character mapping on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: this reads more like directly fishing for a library where a group has made that effort - otherwise there might be a (worse) solution using OCR if you're only interested in ones which might be one of the 26(52)ish ASCII letters

Comment: Just use something like  https://texteditor.com/font-converter/ to generate the mapping for the 52 characters for all the font styles, but somehow your small-caps X is a "'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA'" so your mileage may vary.